# Obj-c UITableView reloadData

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UIViewController with 2 UITableView's added to the .xib and declared in the .h
and then

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (rss1_tblController == nil) {
        rss1_tblController = [[RSS_CostumeTblViewController alloc] init];
    }
    if (rss2_tblController == nil) {
        rss2_tblController = [[RSS_CostumeTblViewController alloc] init];
    }

    [rss1_tblView setDataSource:rss1_tblController];
    [rss2_tblView setDataSource:rss2_tblController];

    [rss1_tblView setDelegate:rss1_tblController];
    [rss2_tblView setDelegate:rss2_tblController];

    rss1_tblController.view = rss1_tblController.tableView;
    rss2_tblController.view = rss2_tblController.tableView;
}
```

but in the RSS_CostumeTblViewController i parse some xml and i need to reloadData on the corresponding table
but wen the process ends i call `[self.tableView reloadData];` from within RSS_CostumeTblViewController and the only method fired is

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

doing basecly nothing...

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

If `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;` is the only method triggered, it looks like it returns 0.
Double check that method to return the correct count of rows.

Comment: I don't really understand where `rss1_tblView` and `rss2_tblView` come from. Also if `RSS_CostumeTblController`'s `numberOfRows...` returns the correct count, I see no possibility, that `cellForRowAtIndexPath...` isn't triggered too.